# How to write custom views for admin in django?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have user list in the user admin which has a column named domain (email-domain), Now when a user logs in with his mail id, he should only see users of his domain, not other domains. For ex if sourabh@gmail.com is logging in then only gmail users should be visible.

[image: Admin screenshot]

---

**admin.py**

```py
from .models import User
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin

class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):

    list_display = ('email', 'domain','admin', 'is_active', 'is_staff')
    list_filter = ('admin', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'groups', 'domain')
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password', 'domain')}),
        ('Permissions',{ 'fields': (
            'is_active', 
            'is_staff', 
            'is_superuser', 
        )}),
    )

    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )
    search_fields = ('email',)
    ordering = ('email',)
    filter_horizontal = ()


admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

---

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models


class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, email, password, domain, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(
            email=email,
            domain = domain,
            is_staff=is_staff, 
            is_active=True,
            is_superuser=is_superuser, 
            **extra_fields
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password, domain, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, domain, False, False, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, domain, **extra_fields):
        user=self._create_user(email, password, domain, True, True, **extra_fields)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    domain = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'

    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False) # a superuser

    objects = MyUserManager()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually explicitly covered in [the admin documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset); you should override `get_queryset`.

```
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    ...
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(domain=request.user.domain)
```